# http/html/ajax: show result before site is completely processed

Tags: html, ajax, cgi

I am looking for a way to show in a webapp in front of a task a wait-message and after it hide the message. The task is running a longer time. I dont know if it is possible at all.

The problem is, so far I can see, that the site will be returned to the users browser AFTER the task is completed because the task is part of the site as a inline code replaces by the webserver interpreter (no matter if PHP, Perl or whatever).

The only solution I can imagine is to parallel the task with threads or processes and requery the state with ajax in the website.

Any idea to do it less complex? Thanks for help!

Comment: what I understood that you show a loading bar when a request is sent and then you hide the loading message after you get response from the server, the problem you are facing is the loading message disapearse before the task or the requests completes.
is that what you ment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server should start sending content to the browser as soon as your code starts executing; it does not wait for the server-side code to finish first.

Therefore, you can just run the task after rendering the HTML containing the wait message.  After the task, you can render a `<script>` block that hides the wait message.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. I thought therefore the browser starts displaying not before the end of the site is reached.

Comment: It works for me.  What language are you using? Does it have buffering options or a `flush` method?

Comment: Are you running CGI? php won't stream in cgi mode unless you use fastCGI or somthing.

Comment: I use mason. It is a template engine over mod_perl.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways you can do this:

1) Pull the task out into its own file so it isn't inline. Then use asynchronous AJAX to query the task. Display a progress bar on firing of the event, and hide it when it is done.

2) Make sure you are streaming your data back to the browser (This is the default in php.). **If you are running php as a CGI it will execute the whole script before returning anything to the browser. In this case you will have to o #1**  Put the inline task as the LAST thing on the page. In the place where the inline task is now, put up a `<div id=loading>Content Loading Please Wait</div>`  or spinner/progress bar.

Capture the output of the inline task into a php variable  At the end of the task add `<script>document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML ="$taskResult";</script>`

Comment: I tried this. And that will not show my wait-div.

------------------
<div id="x" style="display:none;">
wait
</div>


<script>
document.getElementById("x").style.display='block';
</script>

% sleep (10);


<script>
document.getElementById("x").style.display='none';
</script>
------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

See [Watching long processes through CGI](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col39.html). You could adapt the same technique to display updates using AJAX calls.